# What board game for 2 to 4 players with 1 token each and the winner is the first to the top of a raised platform?

Tags: identify-this-game

The game in question I remember playing in the 90s but was an 70s or 80s game.

It is for 2 to 4 players where each player had one coloured token. The board was made up of a player in each corner with the aim to be the first to the top of a raised platform in the centre of the board.

I believe you had to do a lap of the board first and then start going up a platform of steps moving away from each player's corner and connecting at the top to a 1 inch square platform. The platform was raised about 15-20cm above the board with empty space underneath and the platform and steps were in white plastic.

I can't remember the name of it and is bugging me!

I will add a crude drawing when I get a chance. But it's neither Ludo nor Egyptian themed. I don't know the manufacturer although it could have been MB but I'm not sure.

Here is a very crude non turner winning drawing of it as requested:

[image]

Comment: Do you recall if movement involved a spinner with colours on it? Also, are you sure that is was not for 6 players?

Comment: There were only 4 players, 1 for each of the corners of the board. It was a throw of the dice based turn system each player taking a turn 100% not a spinner

Comment: Do you think you could produce a drawing of it. I don't give up and, each time I run through hundreds of games in books and in on-line auctions, I keep an image of what I think your game should look like.

Comment: See attached i'm not much of an artist i'm afraid but hopefully helps?

Answer (score 5):

The game's description corresponds a type of **Chinesenspiel**.

I identified it earlier this year.
In the reference link I provide, you have to scroll down because my answer has not received enough upvotes to appear at the top of the page.

[probably antique French game - asking for identification](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/40553/probably-antique-french-game-asking-for-identification/47207#47207)

To play, a six-sided die is used, with the four colours on the board each represented by a coloured square on one of the die faces. The 2 unused die faces are white.

[image: Chinesenspiel]

Since yours is more recent, it could simple be a variant of the **Parcheesi** family of games. For marketing purposes, it could have been named anything; for example, "Trouble", or "Voice of The Mummy", or "Dark Tower" 
(Edit : I deleted the images of these games since they are clearly not the game you seek).

Does your game at all resemble this one,
**Sacrificial Offering The Board Game**, 
which is definitely Chinesenspiel-inspired?

[image: Sacrificial Offering The Board Game]

Comment: Your picture doesn't feature a raised platform or white plastic steps.  Are there other versions of the game with the described features?

Comment: @Arcanist Lupus : I had forgotten the link to the page - added it. As for the raised platform or white plastic steps, there are none because the one in the photograph is from the early 1900s, and plastic implies it's post-WW2, There are innumerable versions of games of the Pacheesi family, but they usually move in and out toward the centre to form a cross. Chinesenspiel is unique in that you go around the perimeter before ascending to to centre. Finding the exact one among the thousands of versions produced will be daunting. See Grunfeld, Frederic V., "Games of The World", 1975, pp. 27-33.

Comment: Thanks, it does look visually similar to the game in the first picture except if the inner lanes and centre were raised and plastic. The die had numbers instead of colours.

Deffo not like Trouble or Ludo as there was only one playable token. Is there any way to find the modern variants of the older games like Chinesenspiel? as it is a sentimental reason for me wanting to find the specific game in question

Thanks

Comment: @Scott Barrett : More information would help. In what year did you play it? Was in new, or how old? How certain are you that it was a Milton-Bradley game? In what country did you play it? How was it acquired (from older people or bought in a store)?

Comment: @Scott Barrett : I also added "Voice of The Mummy" and "Dark Tower" above as a possible answers.

Comment: It was in the UK, i played with my grandparents they had a number of board games some which belonged to my cousin who is about 15yrs older than me though i don't know if this was one of hers. I remember we played it from at least 4yrs old til going on 10 or older, i was born in 1987 it was a second hand or older game at the time hence me thinking at least 80s or older. 

I'm not certain that it was an MB game, i don't know the manufacturer at all, i do remember the board being very light and possible light blue with white squares for the track, tokens were red, blue green and yellow,

Comment: Edit : I deleted the images of "Trouble", "Voice of The Mummy"and "Dark Tower" since they are clearly not the game you seek.